# Show input elements after select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where depending on users choice, the input elements are visible or not. Actually, the user is setting a defined type of partner in another form, with the elements that are allowed to be visible on that type of partner if selected

Type 1 would have this elements visible:

```
<input type="text" id="partner" name="partner" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->partner;?>" />
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->address;?>" />
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->phone;?>" />
```

Type 2 would have as visible elements:

```
<input type="text" id="partner" name="partner" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->partner;?>" />
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->country;?>" />
<input type="text" id="markname" name="markname" class="span12" value="<?= $partner->markname;?>" />
```

Type 3 is supposed to have them all.

The partner form will start with a select box like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Type 1</option>
    <option>Type 2</option>
    <option>Type 3</option>
</select>
```

The user can definde new visual types and therefore the partner page has to be dynamic.
The page will start by showing only the select box and after selection the elements allowed by the selected type would be displayed.

I know it has to be done by ajax, but I do not now how how to keep them all in same page and refresh the content without refreshing the page

Comment: does the select end up posting back to the server? It sounds like you should only need an on change event.

Comment: The select is a required field in the form, it will end up saved on the server, but it will not post back to the server. On select change, based on the selection, the form will show only fields previously allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("select").on("change", function(){ 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url: "/link-to-post-to", 
        data: $("select").val(), 
        success: function(data){ 
            //append to page here 
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, status, error){ 
            console.log(error) 
        } 
    }); 
 });
```

so the php container will print out the html, then in the jquery it will add it to the page.

Comment: Yes, that I thought about also, but, the number of fields allowed is pretty large, there are about 15 inputs allowed, and the posibilities of grouping would be endless. So, I guess that first I have to build some kind of array with types and allowed elements, and depending on selection I have to display or not the divs containing the input

Comment: you could use a json object to build your values.

Comment: I am storing the allowed inputs on a table on the server, where the values are 1 for allowed and 0 for hidden.

Comment: In your example I have the same input twice, I would like to avoid redeclaration of fields..

Comment: ahh ok, i would need to see a little more code to give you an accurate answer. could you post a sample record returned from the db

Comment: Let's say the user selects Type 1:
Returned database fields are:
Type: 1
partner: 1
address: 1
phone: 1
country: 0
markname: 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57574/discussion-between-eg-dac-and-rosuandreimihai).